# Sandbox: bash(13945) deny(1) file-read-data /myappPath/ios/.xcode.env (in target 'myappName' from project 'myappName')

Tags: xcode

```
Sandbox: bash(13945) deny(1) file-read-data /myAppProjectPath/ios/.xcode.env (in target 'myapp' from project 'myapp')
/Path/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Emotion-acmdlvvlqstlgranaydxcxmpemsf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Emotion.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Emotion.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh: line 3: /myAppProjectPath/ios/Pods/../.xcode.env: Operation not permitted
```

Error when building an app on xcode. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Go to your project's target -> "Build Settings" tab -> "Build Options" section and select "No" to "User Script Sandboxing"

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen after I let Xcode update the project to "recommended settings." That failed with a merge error, likely leaving the project file in a bad state. Note that in the build output window it should specify an error. The fix for me was to revert the Xcode project file (via Git), clean the project build folder, and rebuild.